# How to build a bluethoot button transmisor

Tags: android, button, bluetooth, slave

I have a mobile app witch has a feature to recive by bluethoot a command to do stuffs. What I dont know is how to buy only this bluethoot device. There are some like flic.io, but I want my brand to use with the app. There are generic chips with bluethoot witch I can put into a plastic recipient with buttons like the selfies?
What is the name of this kind of devices???

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking for examples which have developer documentation like TI Sensor Tag or HTC Fetch or something more stationary than a bluetooth low energy tag?

Comment: Yes, is like the HTC Fetch. A button to send a command to the phone. Then my app does what I want.

Comment: Look at chip inside TI sensor tag (old and new) and (off topic) look for Chinese manufacturer to make your branded button. Good luck.